# Windows Speech API questions

Tags: windows, speech-recognition

I've got two questions for using the Windows Speech API.

First:  I've got my Speech Recognizer set up to detect sentences of a specific structure--namely a verb followed by a noun, with some wildcard stuff in between.  However, I also would it like it to be able to recognize a "Help" and "Exit" command that would not fit this structure.  How can I get the grammar to recognize another, fundamentally different, structure?

Second:  I am using SemanticResultValue to analyze the content of my sentences.  I want there to be multiple words that users can say for the same verb--for example, "Go," "Walk," and "Run" would all translate to the same action in the system.  How do I assign multiple values to the same SemanticResultValue?

Answer (score 1):

1)  Multiple grammars would be the obvious solution here; one grammar for your verb/noun, and a separate grammar for pure verbs.

2) The SemanticResultValue constructor that takes a GrammarBuilder parameter ([`SemanticResultValue (GrammarBuilder, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554252%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) would be appropriate here.